# Editing Outlook 2013 Signatures Remotely

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I need to edit multiple users Outlook 2013 signatures(we have a template that everyone uses). Rather than manually going on each of their computers and changing them is there a way to change it remotely without disturbing their workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using Exchange, you will need to edit directly in Outlook or OWA, as its a client side thing only. You will need credential access to the mailbox to change it remotely. Exchange has some things you can do at the transport level to get some standardization out of it. This also assumes you are filling out all the attributes of your users in Active Directory.

This link has some info on how to accomplish this via Exchange. http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/standardized-signatures-exchange-server-2010-